# How to fix error "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: python, php, localhost

This issue occurred while I am on Windows 11

```
$output = shell_exec('python localhost\project\datacatcher.py 2>&1');
echo($output);
```

When I try to get my php file to execute this python program, it returns this error. I have tried reinstalling Python with "Add Python 3.11.3 to PATH" enabled and also tried making sure that a python.exe file was in the environmental variables, but they haven't worked. The php file is called when I submit an HTML form, and all the other code in it seems to work. I just can't seem to find a way to get my PHP file to execute my python file. I tried using exec() but I don't think it worked either. Any help or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

I was trying to get a php file to execute a python source file. I expected the php code to be able to return a result to show that it did successfully executed. Instead, when the HTML calls the PHP file, all the other parts of the PHP file execute without error; it is just the last portion that I can't find a way around. I just need to find a method to be able to execute python code from PHP without errors. Help Greatly Appreciated.

---

**EDIT**: I have fixed the problem thanks to the generous help of Marcin Orlowski

The solution was:

```
$command = 'C:\PROGRA~1\Python311\python.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\project\datacatcher.py 2>&1';
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

There is a space between the .exe and the 2nd C:

Comment: use absolute path to `python`? also you can print your environment variables from PHP script to see what is i.e. `PATH` there

Comment: Actually, thank you very much for your help! Using absolute path to python did seem to help. For other people seeing this,                                                                   $output = shell_exec('C:\Python311\python.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\project\datacatcher.py 2>&1');
echo($output);